# How to enable a disabled step in Semantic UI with Javascript (jQuery or Angular)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I am learning Semantic UI with Javascript and I got stuck at the "step enabling" (see code below) I have 5 steps that need to be enabled in order each after 5 seconds. How can I do it with javascript?

```
<div class="ui five steps">
    <div class="disabled step">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title"> `do first step` </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="disabled step">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title"> `do second step` </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using vanilla js.

```js
var steps = document.querySelectorAll('.step'),
    total = steps.length,
    count = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(steps, function(node, i){
    if(node.classList.contains('disabled') && i === count) {
      node.classList.remove('disabled');
    }
  });
  if(++count >= total) clearInterval(timer);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui five steps">
    <div class="disabled step">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title"> `do first step` </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="disabled step">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title"> `do second step` </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="disabled step">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title"> `do third step` </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="disabled step">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title"> `do fourth step` </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="disabled step">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title"> `do fifth step` </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```